How to host Core WCF host on Ubuntu to access a database running in Ubuntu
I have an Ubuntu server hosted in the cloud, and it has a postgres database hosted in a Docker container. I now have a Windows application needing access to the database. I want to have a service layer in between this Postgres database (in Ubuntu) and the Windows-based application.
Now I am finding a feasible solution for this cross operating system scenario where an application is .NET based and the database is hosted in Ubuntu.
I thought Core WCF might solve it or a Windows Docker container hosted in  an Ubuntu machine and on that host Core WCF/Services. Do you have any experience to share with about Core WCF or any new proposal to solve this problem?
